# Getting Harvard style with natbib

Tags: natbib

I'd really like to have a custom bibliography which matches the Harvard style shown in the photo attached. I heard that Agsm achieved something similar. Is this the case?[image]

Comment: I think you should look into the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package. Open a command window, type `latex makebst`, and follow the menu-driven system through of a lot of questions, each with multiple choices. At the end of the process, you'll have a bespoke bibliography style file which implements all of your formatting needs.

Comment: You wrote, "I heard that Agsm achieved something similar." Well, did you give it a try? What did you learn?

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> I heard that `agsm` achieve[s] something similar. Is this the case?

I guess the answer to your question depends on what you mean by "similar".

Consider the following screenshot, generated with the `natbib` citation management package and the `agsm` bibliography style. (See further below for the code that gives rise to the screenshot.)

[image]

I can spot at least five [5] discrepancies between what `agsm` produces and what you say you must achieve in terms of formatting the citation call-outs and bibliographic entries:

- The "et al." in the citation call-out produced by `agsm` is not in *italics*.
- The `agsm` style does not employ an "Oxford comma" in the name list.
- The `agsm` style does not insert a comma after the name of the journal.
- The `agsm` style renders the volume number in **bold**.
- The `agsm` style fails to provide a "pp." string before the page range.

And all this just for an entry of type `@article`. Incidentally, if I hadn't added the instruction `\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}`, two additional discrepancies would occur.

No telling which discrepancies might show up with entries of type `@book`, `@techreport`, `@incollection`, `@misc`, and `@unpublished`, to name just a few alternative entry types.

This is why I suggested in an earlier comment that if you must adhere to the formatting guidelines you showed in your posting, you should give very serious thought to running the `makebst` utility and creating a bespoke bibliography style that incorporates all of your required formatting requirements from the get-go.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{norrie-etal:2012,
    author  = "Caroline Norrie and John Hammond and 
               Lynda D'Avray and Valentina Collington 
               and Jan Fook", 
    title   = "Doing it Differently? {A} Review of 
               Literature on Teaching Reflective Practice 
               across Health and Social Care Professions",
    journal = "Reflective Practice",
    year    = 2012,
    volume  = 13,
    number  = 4,
    pages   = "565-578",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
\citep{norrie-etal:2012}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```